# How to configure PAM to allow 'su' to user5 from any user?

Tags: linux, su, pam

I have to use the service /etc/pam.d/su to allow any user in my sistem to do

```
su user5
```

and not password requires.

I tried with this but it does not work:

```
auth       [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = user5
```

Comment: This is probably a better fit for either ServerFault or Unix SE (http://unix.stackexchange.com/), as what you're doing is configuration rather than programming.

Comment: That said, have you configured PAM to do debug-level logging to syslog? If you had an error message, that would be a lot more useful than "does not work". (See also http://serverfault.com/questions/249671/switch-on-pam-debugging-to-syslog)

Comment: There is not any error message, I tried to have the identity of user5 after to put this line in su file, but it still requires the password.

Comment: That's the thing -- if you turn on debug logging, there'll be *some* kind of message if it's invoked at all, even if the result is success. So TURN ON THE BLOODY LOGGING, and include the logs in the question (when you re-ask the question somewhere on-topic, ie. Unix SE or ServerFault). That way we can at least tell that your directive is really invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Consider simply:

```
# consider success given a match, but continue on to other auth steps in addition
auth pam_succeed_if.so user = user5
```

...or...

```
# perform no further auth steps if this succeeds
auth [success=done] pam_succeed_if.so user = user5
```

The `success=ignore default=1` flags are meaningful in a scenario where the **immediate next** module is something you want to execute for user5 but skip for all other users. That scenario isn't what you describe as your intent.

---

That said, `su` may not be the right tool for this job at all. Consider a setuid binary (such as a shell) owned by `user5` (with the immutable flag set, or on a read-only filesystem, if you don't actually want user5 to be able to modify it).